# Incorrect Basin Tracing

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am conducting hydrological analysis for a catchment.
To make the DTM, I use mosaic to new raster tool.
I fill the DTM.
I make a flow direction layer.
I use the flow direction layer as input to the basin tool to show basins.

BUT... ArcMAP is merging two basins together when it should not.
See image.

[image]

I want to remove the basin to the west.

I tried reclassifying by increasing classes but the result is still the same with 32 (maximum) classes.

I tried this in MATLAB and it traced the catchment correctly. Maybe I am doing something wrong or it is simply an issue with ArcMAP not identifying basin divides properly? I have also tried three different DTM with different spatial extent and the result is the same as the attached image.

I am using ArcMAP version 10.4.

Comment: Are you sure this is not just an artifact of the color scheme you are using?  Try symbolizing with unique colors.